# Responsive website not displaying correctly

Tags: iphone, mobile, responsive

I'm fairly new to the site but find it awesome, great expertise going around. I have a small issue with a site not displaying 100% right on mobile phones. It is build responsive and I'm of the impression it was working fine initially, but something changed along the line. The site adjusts itself to mobile screens but it does not scale properly and you must reduce it manually to see it all in the screen.
I'm not a real developer but it should be very easy fix I think. Hope someone can help.

Below my code:

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){

```
.hide-for-small{ display: none; }
#mesh-left{ display: none; }
#mesh-right{ display: none; }

.push-half{ left: 0; }
.pull-half{ right: 0; }

.square-box{ min-width: 100%; padding: 33px 11px 22px 11px; }
.box-title{ background: none !important; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100% !important; }
.box-title h4{ color: #222 !important; }

.form-title{ width: 100%; top: 0px; text-align: center; }
#form-holder select{ width: 100%; }
.form-input input{ width: 100%; }
.form-input textarea{ width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 100px;  }


.show-for-small{ display: block; }

#contact{ padding: 44px 15px 44px 15px; text-align: center !important; }

#logo{ margin-top: 55px; }
.social-header{ top:2%; left: 35%;}
#main-menu{ margin-left:0;}
```

}
@media screen and (max-width: 370px){

```
.hide-for-small{ display: none; }
#mesh-left{ display: none; }
#mesh-right{ display: none; }

.push-half{ left: 0; }
.pull-half{ right: 0; }

.square-box{ min-width: 100%; padding: 33px 11px 22px 11px; }
.box-title{ background: none !important; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100% !important; }
.box-title h4{ color: #222 !important; }

.form-title{ width: 100%; top: 0px; text-align: center; }
#form-holder select{ width: 100%; }
.form-input input{ width: 100%; }
.form-input textarea{ width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 100px;  }


.show-for-small{ display: block; }

#contact{ padding: 44px 15px 44px 15px; text-align: center !important; }

#logo{ margin-top: 55px; }
.social-header{ top: 150px; left: 35%; }
#main-menu{ margin-left:0;}
```

}

/***** TABLETS PORTRAIT & LANDSCAPE *****/

@media all
and (min-width : 768px)
and (max-width : 1024px) {

## mesh-left{ left: -280px !important; }

## mesh-right{ right: -360px !important; }

}

/***** PORTRAIT TABLETS *****/

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {

}

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your `<head> </head>` tag to enable css to correctly detect the screen width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for develope responsive, mobile web applications

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok but is there a way to fix current site without putting a new system in place?

Comment: If you want someone to help you. Copy the source code of the page with your css and put, for example on https://jsfiddle.net/